# Replace old path to new path

Tags: java

I have below mentioned full path string:

```
String originalpath = C:\test\sample\batchmatch\internal\a\b\a.pdf
```

I need to replace first part of the path with new path

For example:

```
oldpath =  C:\test\sample\batchmatch\internal\to 
new path = C:\testdemo\sampledemo\batchmatchdemo\internal
```

I have tried below mentioned approach, but it doesn't work.

```
String newpath = originalpath.replaceAll(oldpath,newpath);
```

Could you please help me?

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originalpath = C:\test\sample\batchmatch\internal\a\b\a.pdf;
        String oldpath =  C:\test\sample\batchmatch\internal\;
        String newpath = C:\testdemo\sampledemo\batchmatchdemo\internal;
        String relacepath = a.replaceAll(oldpath ,newpath);
        System.out.println("replacepath::"+ relacepath );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `replaceAll`? Your requirements aren't very clear.

Comment: Show the real runnable code that you are using that reproduces the problem, not some approximation that cannot be run. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @tnw Requirement is I need to replace  C:\test\sample\batchmatch\internal\  to C:\testdemo\sampledemo\batchmatchdemo\internal

Answer (score 1):

This should be a bit flexible for you irrespective of your platform (i.e `\` or `/`)

```
    String oldPath =  "C:\\test\\sample\\batchmatch\\internal\\a\\b\\a.pdf".replaceAll("(\\\\+|/+)", "/");
    String newPath = "C:\\testdemo\\sampledemo\\batchmatchdemo\\internal".replaceAll("(\\\\+|/+)", "/");

    String partToKeep = "\\a\\b\\a.pdf".replaceAll("(\\\\+|/+)", "/");
    String partToReplace = oldPath.substring(0, oldPath.indexOf(partToKeep));

    String replacedPath = oldPath.replaceAll(partToReplace, newPath).replaceAll("(\\\\+|/+)", Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("file.separator")));
    System.out.println(replacedPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String originalpath = "C:/test/sample/batchmatch/internal/a/b/a.pdf";
    String oldpath =  "C:/test/sample/batchmatch/internal";
    String path = "C:/testdemo/sampledemo/batchmatchdemo/internal";
    System.out.println(originalpath);
    String newpath = originalpath.replaceAll(oldpath,path);

    System.out.println(newpath);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do this  as for example :

```
    String communPath = "C:/test/sample/batchmatch/internal";
    String secondpartOfPath = "/a/b/a.pdf";
    String originalpath = communPath.concat(secondpartOfPath);
    String newPath = "C:/testdemo/sampledemo/batchmatchdemo/internal";
    System.out.println(originalpath);
    String path = originalpath.replaceAll(communPath, newPath);
    System.out.println(path );
```

originalpath : C:/test/sample/batchmatch/internal/a/b/a.pdf

path  : C:/testdemo/sampledemo/batchmatchdemo/internal/a/b/a.pdf